# Disabling the dropdown for select tag from the method in Polymer Dom-module not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, templates, dom

I am trying to disable the country dropdown based on disabled_value value got from backend code

If the value of disabled_value is 0, hide the dropdown and make it not selectable dropdown

If the value of disabled_value is 1, make the dropdown to select the country available

```
<dom-module>
<template>
<div>
    <select disabled="[[ _disableDropdown ]]">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ country_list_and_code ]]">
            <option value="[[ item.0 ]]” value>[[ item.1 ]]</option>
        </template>
    </select>
</div>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: ‘country’,
    properties: {
        disabled_value: {
            type: Number,
        },
    },

    _disableDropdown: function(disabled_value) {
        if (disabled_value) {
            return disabled_value.disabled;
        } else {
            return disabled_value.enabled;
        }
    }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

This is the HTML tag I get from the code

```
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>                       
<option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>      
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="DZ">United States</option>
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

- If the disabled_value is 0, then only show the United States country in the dropdown and disabled the selection in dropdown
- If the disabled_value is 1, then only show all the countries in the dropdown and allow selection in dropdown

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to set or not to set attribut "disabled", for example https://jsfiddle.net/k0wnu3p1/4/

```
<select name="tagging" disabled>
        <option selected>I'm working</option>
        <option value="Option B">Option B</option>
        <option value="Option C">Option C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am trying to get this from a method as I mentioned in my code. Isn't that possible based on disabled_value ? I am trying to find that dynamic way out

Comment: Have you if method in your template?
`if([[ _disableDropdown ]])
   <select disabled>
else
  <select>`

Comment: I dint try this. I have added my code whatever is there in the code I added

Comment: Is it possible to update that in your code you already added, since I dint understand what you are trying to say @Evgeniya

Comment: Through my link you can see how the attribute  disabled works. Your code 
gives out <select disabled="1"> or <select disabled="0">, browser see both selects as disabled.
I suggest you use "if" in order to get <select disabled> or <select>